# LaTeX - Is it possible to change font size to 13pt after using "mathptmx"?

Tags: fonts, latex

I want to change the font size to 13pt in LaTeX, while using the Times font family (with mathptmx). However, I always get the error message "Unused global option(s):", referring to the font size of "13pt" specified in the documentclass options (see example below).

How can I set the font size to 13pt throughout the whole document after using "mathptmx"?

I couldn't find any solution by doing extensive research on the internet.

```
\documentclass[13pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin={2cm},rmargin={2cm},tmargin={2cm},bmargin={2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could select `13pt` with `\fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont`, but with `mathptmx`, this won't help you because the font does not contain glyphs for `13pt` and will use `12pt` instead.

Bottom line: if you really must have `13pt`, use another font which does have 13pt glyphs. A similar font is e.g. `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} \fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont`